# SUM in mysql with customers and excursions

Tags: mysql, sql

Good Night,

The objetive is to know the sum of all the excursions in my mysql table.

My sql tables are like that.

```
Excursion
ID Excursion_Name Excursion_date Excursion_capacity
1  Exc1             date 1              10
2  Exc2             date 1              15
```

Here date 1 is the excursions departure date(I wrote date1 just to show that both excursions are on the same day)

```
Booking
Id Excursion_id
1      1
2      1
```

Booking is the table where all the bookings are saved.

```
Booking_price
booking_id price_id quantity
1             1        2
1             2        0
```

Booking_price is because we have different prices like adults, childs and so on

we also have a table called "Price" where is stored all the information about prices with a reference to the excursion.

I just wanted to get that kind of table.

```
Excursion_id       free_tickets(booked_tickets - capacity)
1                              8
2                             15
```

Thanks to all of you!

Comment: What are you actually asking for help with?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```sql
SELECT e.id excursion_id, 
       e.excursion_capacity - COALESCE(q.quantity, 0) free_tickets
  FROM excursion e LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT b.excursion_id, SUM(p.quantity) quantity
    FROM booking b JOIN booking_price p
      ON b.id = p.booking_id
   GROUP BY b.excursion_id
) q
     ON e.id = q.excursion_id
```

or

```sql
SELECT e.id excursion_id, 
       MAX(e.excursion_capacity) - COALESCE(SUM(p.quantity), 0) free_tickets
  FROM excursion e LEFT JOIN booking b 
    ON e.id = b.excursion_id LEFT JOIN booking_price p
    ON b.id = p.booking_id
 GROUP BY e.id
```

Output:

```
| EXCURSION_ID | FREE_TICKETS |
|--------------|--------------|
|            1 |            8 |
|            2 |           15 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/666ab1/6)** demo for both queries

Comment: The second one is my solution, but max is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    e.Id, 
    e.Excursion_capacity - SUM(ifnull(bp.Quantity,0)) AS free_tickets 
FROM 
    Excursion e
LEFT JOIN 
    Booking b on e.Id = b.Excursion_id
LEFT JOIN 
    Booking_price bp on b.id = bp.Booking_id
GROUP BY
    e.Id
```